# What is wrong in $(\frac{1}{8})^{-\frac{1}{3}}$?

Tags: roots, exponentiation

I tried this:

$$\biggl (\frac{1}{8}\biggr)^{-\frac{1}{3}}= \frac{1^{-\frac{1}{3}}}{8^{-{\frac{1}{3}}}}=\frac{-\sqrt[3]{1}}{-\sqrt[3]{8}}=\frac{-1}{-2}$$

Also, is it possible to see what I don't understand here or are there maybe several things..

Comment: $a^{-b}$ is not equal to $-a^b$. Check what your book says about negative exponents.

Comment: can I suggest to change title from "how to solve..." to "whats is wrong in..." ? You seem more interested in know where is the error in your calculation that in a different method to make the same calculation.

Comment: Hint: $(1/8)^{-1/3}=8^{1/3}$.

Comment: I see I made a mistake with negative exponents. But I think it's your hint I don't understand. What is it that makes 1/8 = 8 by removing the negative? After this I see what to do by the definition of what roots are x^3 = 8 which is 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use $$a^{-x} = \frac 1{a^x} \tag1$$ and $$a^{1/n}= \sqrt[n]{a} \tag 2$$

Therefore $$\left(\frac 18 \right)^{- 1/3} = \frac{1^{-1/3}}{8^{-1/3}}=\frac{1/1^{1/3}}{1/8^{1/3}}= \frac{1/\sqrt[3]1}{1/\sqrt[3]8} = \frac{1}{1/2}=2$$

Comment: If $a^{-n} = \frac{1}{a^n}$ then i can do it like this: $\biggl (\frac{1}{8}\biggr)^{-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{8^\frac{1}{3}}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{8}}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{2}}=2$ ?

Comment: @ReducedGosling Yes that's correct, too.

Answer (score 1):

there are some simple algebraic errors there, for instance 
$$a^{-\frac{1}{b}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt[b]{a}}$$
not 
$$ a^{-\frac{1}{b}} = -\sqrt[b]{a} $$

then

$$ \left(\frac{1}{8}\right)^{-\frac{1}{3}} = \sqrt[3]8 = 2 $$

Comment: i think the minus sign in $$-\sqrt[b]{a}$$ is wrong, ah i oversee the word "NOT"

Comment: IMO, there are no other errors.

Answer (score 0):

$$(1/8)^{-1/3}=((1/8)^{1/3})^{-1}=(1/2)^{-1}=2$$